# How do I load a byte[] array into a structure in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, arrays

Consider following structure where the length of both `username` and `password` is 17:

```
struct LoginPacket
{
    public int unk1;
    public string username;
    public string password;
}
```

Also this byte array

```
00 00 00 00 6A 6D 32 6D 65 00 72 00 7A 76 72 00 98 FD 18 00 A0 68 65 72 65 49 73
70 61 73 73 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 31 2E 30 30 2E 30 30 00 00 00 C7 9D 72 00 04 00
00 31 2E 31 30 2E 32 37 00 0C 2C F6 24 16 2C F6 24 16
```

Is it possible to load this byte array into the above structure? There is something called `Marshal`, but it doesn't quite work for me.

Comment: How are the strings encoded? ASCII? UTF8?

Comment: Add public static LogicPacket Parse(Byte[] bytes){} method to struct. Otherwise you can write unsafe implementation (not sure)

Comment: @Albin: It looks like unicode.

Comment: @Jeff: Unicode isn't an encoding!

Comment: ya its utf8. the thing is there are around 100 packets total and i thought it would be easier to make structures for each packet. would be easier for future edits.

Comment: Is the length of 17 in bytes, or characters?

Comment: @Will: My mistake.  When it comes to this, I tend to mix the terms up.  I went by the terms used in the `Encoding` class.  I meant UTF-16.  (better? :)  I saw the `0`'s intermixed there and that was my first impression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you are, this answer uses the marshalling system in .NET. The structure itself contains the recipe on how to decipher a byte array. If you can't do that, you need manual code.

```
void Main()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[]
    {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x32, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x7A, 0x76, 0x72, 0x00, 0x98, 0xFD, 0x18, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x65, 0x49, 0x73,
        0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC7, 0x9D, 0x72, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x32, 0x37, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x2C, 0xF6, 0x24, 0x16, 0x2C, 0xF6, 0x24, 0x16
    };

    var packet = BytesToStructure<LoginPacket>(bytes);
    packet.Dump();
}

static T BytesToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    if (bytes.Length < size)
        throw new Exception("Invalid parameter");

    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    try
    {
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);
        return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
struct LoginPacket
{
    public int unk1;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=17)]
    public string username;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=17)]
    public string password;
}
```

When executed in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) you get this:

```
unk1: 0 
username: jm2me 
password: hereIspass
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming strings are in UTF8 encoding. If not, replace UTF8 with your encoding

```
struct LoginPacket
{
    public int unk1;
    public string username;
    public string password;

    public void Parse(byte[] b)
    {
        unk1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
        username = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b, 4, 17);
        password = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b, 4 + 17, 17);
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually looks like fastest and easiest way so far. With struct constructor it will work perfectly for my project. Thumbs up for this answer so far.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work. You are interpreting the first 17 bytes as UTF-8. This doesn't necessarily mean 17 characters. It can even mean you are trying to interpret half of an original character as UTF8

Comment: The client is fixed to send 17 bytes for username only a-z0-9 UTF8 so I think I should be good.

Comment: You will see, that it is not going to work. If the client would use UTF-8 and send only the characters you said, the sample data would be 38 bytes long. But it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to use `Encoding.GetString(byte[])` to get your bytes.

So you'd need to represent your bytes as a `byte[]` and then use the above method to convert it to to a string.

```
LoginPacket packet;

byte[] mybytes = "..." //your bytes

packet.username = Encoding.GetBytes(mybytes);
```

etc...

You might need to have several byte arrays each containing the bytes for your different struct fields.  If (starting from beginning) each field is 17 bytes, that shouldn't be too hard, if that isn't the case, it will depend on how you know where each field starts in your byte array

Comment: That would work, but I would lvoe to use struct cause in future i can edit packet structures easly.

Comment: @user621033: You can use the struct, but you have to get your bytes from wherever they come from into the struct, right? So this is my advice on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use unsafe code:

```
        byte[] packetBytes;

        LoginPacket lp = new LoginPacket();
        lp.unk1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(packetBytes, 0);
        fixed (byte* buffer = &packetBytes[4])
        {
            lp.username = Marshal.PtrToStringUni((IntPtr)buffer);
            lp.password = Marshal.PtrToStringUni((IntPtr)buffer + (IntPtr)Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(lp.username));
        }
```