# Byte Array to Struct UDP Packet

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, udp

I am currently stuck with my project. I currently recieve UDP packets from a game. These packets contain byte arrays. These byte arrays need to be converted to a struct.

I've tackled a previous problem in this question:
[F1 2019 UDP decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231960/f1-2019-udp-decoding)

I have got some part of this to work. I use this code to convert the byte array in to a struct:

```
PacketHeader ByteArrayToPacketHeader(byte[] bytes)
            {
                GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                PacketHeader stuff;
                try
                {
                    stuff = (PacketHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(PacketHeader));
                }
                finally
                {
                    handle.Free();
                }
                return stuff;
            }
```

My Packet Header (Struct) Looks like this:

```
public struct PacketHeader
    {
        public ushort m_packetFormat;         // 2019
        public byte m_gameMajorVersion;     // Game major version - "X.00"
        public byte m_gameMinorVersion;     // Game minor version - "1.XX"
        public byte m_packetVersion;        // Version of this packet type, all start from 1
        public byte m_packetId;             // Identifier for the packet type, see below
        public ulong m_sessionUID;           // Unique identifier for the session
        public float m_sessionTime;          // Session timestamp
        public uint m_frameIdentifier;      // Identifier for the frame the data was retrieved on
        public byte m_playerCarIndex;       // Index of player's car in the array
    };
```

Through this code I get the correct information. So this works!

The game sends multiple "Packets" (Structs) through the same byte array.

But when I use the same code to convert the byte array to the new structlayout I don't get the right information out of the array.
Example:

```
PacketCarTelemetryData ByteArrayToPacketCarTelemetryData(byte[] bytes)
                {
                    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                    PacketCarTelemetryData stuff;
                    try
                    {
                        stuff = (PacketCarTelemetryData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(PacketCarTelemetryData));
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        handle.Free();
                    }
                    return stuff;
```

This code uses this structlayout:

```
public struct PacketCarTelemetryData
    {
         public PacketHeader m_header;        // Header

         public CarTelemetryData m_carTelemetryData;

         public uint m_buttonStatus;        // Bit flags specifying which buttons are being pressed
                                      // currently - see appendices
    };
```

In the struct above there are other structs stored:

```
public struct CarTelemetryData
    {

        public ushort m_speed;                    // Speed of car in kilometres per hour
        public float m_throttle;                 // Amount of throttle applied (0.0 to 1.0)
        public float m_steer;                    // Steering (-1.0 (full lock left) to 1.0 (full lock right))
        public float m_brake;                    // Amount of brake applied (0.0 to 1.0)
        public byte m_clutch;                   // Amount of clutch applied (0 to 100)
        public sbyte m_gear;                     // Gear selected (1-8, N=0, R=-1)
        public ushort m_engineRPM;                // Engine RPM
        public byte m_drs;                      // 0 = off, 1 = on
        public byte m_revLightsPercent;         // Rev lights indicator (percentage)
        public ushort m_brakesTemperature;     // Brakes temperature (celsius)
        public ushort m_tyresSurfaceTemperature; // Tyres surface temperature (celsius)
        public ushort m_tyresInnerTemperature; // Tyres inner temperature (celsius)
        public ushort m_engineTemperature;        // Engine temperature (celsius)
        public float tyresPressure;         // Tyres pressure (PSI)
        public byte m_surfaceType;           // Driving surface, see appendice
    };
```

So my problem now is that when I use this code to convert the byte array to this specific struct I don't get the information I want.

[image: Example Information]

P.s. There are no 36 gears in the car and my brakes are not 21760 degree celcius...

Does anyone have a suggestion?

With kind regards,

Edit:

For more information, this is the hex code I get when I want to read the packet CarTelemetryData:

```
E3-07-01-15-01-06-F8-CE-BE-09-64-7F-EA-D1-DC-A1-16-41-91-01-00-00-13-7B-00-00-00-80-3F-36-53-7E-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-F3-2F-00-64-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-74-00-74-00-4F-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-74-00-00-00-80-3F-1B-F2-3A-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-35-2D-00-22-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-69-00-69-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-7B-00-00-00-80-3F-F3-59-A1-BA-00-00-00-00-00-02-59-2F-00-64-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-72-00-72-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-77-00-00-00-80-3F-FE-5F-3F-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-3D-2E-00-3E-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-71-00-71-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-81-00-00-00-80-3F-89-78-23-3C-00-00-00-00-00-03-E0-28-00-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-77-00-78-00-4F-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-77-00-00-00-80-3F-C3-73-98-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-2F-2E-00-54-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-75-00-75-00-50-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-76-00-00-00-80-3F-F3-F4-BA-BA-00-00-00-00-00-02-21-2E-00-59-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-75-00-75-00-4F-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-7C-00-00-00-80-3F-4D-7D-04-3B-00-00-00-00-00-02-FB-2F-00-64-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-70-00-70-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-75-00-00-00-80-3F-84-45-AB-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-BF-2D-00-31-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-77-00-77-00-4F-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-80-00-00-00-80-3F-B5-8C-BD-3B-00-00-00-00-00-03-1B-28-00-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-71-00-71-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-72-00-00-00-80-3F-F8-D0-87-3A-00-00-00-00-00-02-63-2C-00-37-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-79-00-79-00-4F-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-7B-00-00-00-80-3F-FF-A7-60-3A-00-00-00-00-00-02-DE-2F-00-64-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-6E-00-6E-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-7A-00-00-00-80-3F-B9-2E-2F-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-D1-2F-00-64-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-75-00-75-00-4F-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-74-00-00-00-80-3F-CD-1E-18-3A-00-00-00-00-00-02-3F-2D-00-23-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-6F-00-6F-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-73-00-00-00-80-3F-15-0F-AF-3B-00-00-00-00-00-02-A5-2B-00-0C-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-70-00-70-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-7A-00-00-00-80-3F-2B-C0-14-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-49-2F-00-64-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-6F-00-6F-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-7F-00-00-00-80-3F-41-CA-C0-3C-00-00-00-00-00-03-85-2B-00-64-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-79-00-79-00-4F-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-72-00-00-00-80-3F-07-1F-D5-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-DE-2A-00-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-78-00-78-00-4F-00-4F-00-5B-00-5B-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-71-00-00-00-80-3F-DD-C0-1C-3C-00-00-00-00-00-02-DD-2A-00-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-6F-00-6F-00-4F-00-4F-00-5A-00-5A-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-00-00-AC-41-00-00-AC-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-B8-41-00-00-00-00-31-00-97-96-96-3E-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-9B-17-00-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-1D-00-62-00-62-00-4F-00-4F-00-59-00-59-00-58-00-58-00-5A-00-CD-CC-A8-41-CD-CC-A8-41-33-33-BB-41-33-33-BB-41-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
```

I know that with this information the following numbers don't match with what is happening in the game:

[image: Corrisponding car telemetry data]

The current gear should be: 1. That is one fact I know.

The reflight percentage should be under 100%

The temps should be a lot lower,

The RPM is way to high (Probbably around 10000 is normal).

I hope this is information will suffice.

Comment: what is the *endianness* of the data? how are you *serializing* this data? is it the same code in reverse? I'm worried about padding, basically; the size of PacketHeader is 32, but you're probably expecting 23 or something? is that right?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for your fast reply! What I know is that they decode the array in LittleEndian. I know what it means but don't know what to do with it. Also I have not a clue what serializing is. I am kind of new to this... If you wouldn't mind I would like to learn about this a lot more, so if you can explain it a bit or direct me to some webpage where I can learn about it, I would really appreciate it. With kind regards,

Comment: A lot of desktop CPUs are also little-endian, so: does it work? Do you have a sample payload I could look at here, in hex and the expected values. As it happens, this is my speciality field.

Comment: @MarcGravell I will send the hex to you asap, but the expected values I do not understand. I simply get one huge line of hex code and all the information is stored there. As for your answer below, I got the packetheader working already, but not the rest.

Comment: I'm happy to help you try and get this figured out, but: that's 1347 bytes - what is this meant to be? one header and one telemetry? lots of headers and telemetries one after the other? one header and lots of telemetries? it is way too big for just one of each... help me understand what I'm looking at here

Comment: in particular, I note that 0xE3, 0x07 (i.e. the value `2019` in `m_packetFormat`) only occurs once; presumably the format doesn't change, so ... this is only one header record? but... the header has the frame identifier, so... I would expect it to be? is there a protocol spec for this? it would be a *lot* easier for me to decipher from there...

Comment: @MarcGravell I can surely help you understand what you are looking at. At the forum of codemasters (makers of the game) they specify that all the structs (so many different types) are being send in one array. Here is the site: https://forums.codemasters.com/topic/44592-f1-2019-udp-specification/

Comment: and with that: the problems can be resolved; see new answer

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you so much! I now get the correct information out of the byte array! If I understand it correctly I can use the same method to get the information out of the other Packets? I want to thank you for your time and answers, I couldn't have done it without you! With kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go; there were a few things to look at here; the first is that the `[4]` etc in the specification refers to a *fixed quantity* of those things, not one of them - look at the tyre temperatures, etc; now, you *can* do this with a `fixed` buffer in C#, but that is really painful to use as it requires `unsafe` code, so instead I've just used some custom quad types; I've also explicitly laid out all the structs. Rather than read the header twice, here I'm parsing it sequentially as 20 car instances.

Result: all bytes accounted for; demo code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, Size = 23)]
public struct PacketHeader
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort m_packetFormat;         // 2019
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte m_gameMajorVersion;     // Game major version - "X.00"
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte m_gameMinorVersion;     // Game minor version - "1.XX"
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public byte m_packetVersion;        // Version of this packet type, all start from 1
    [FieldOffset(5)]
    public PacketType m_packetId;             // Identifier for the packet type, see below
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public ulong m_sessionUID;           // Unique identifier for the session
    [FieldOffset(14)]
    public float m_sessionTime;          // Session timestamp
    [FieldOffset(18)]
    public uint m_frameIdentifier;      // Identifier for the frame the data was retrieved on
    [FieldOffset(22)]
    public byte m_playerCarIndex;       // Index of player's car in the array
};

public enum PacketType : byte
{
    Motion = 0, // Contains all motion data for player’s car – only sent while player is in control

    Session = 1,// Data about the session – track, time left

    LapData = 2,//  Data about all the lap times of cars in the session

    Event = 3, // Various notable events that happen during a session

    Participants = 4, // List of participants in the session, mostly relevant for multiplayer

    CarSetups = 5, // Packet detailing car setups for cars in the race

    CarTelemetry = 6,  // Telemetry data for all cars

    CarStatus = 7 //  Status data for all cars such as damage
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, Size = 63)]
public struct CarTelemetryData
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort m_speed;                    // Speed of car in kilometres per hour
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public float m_throttle;                 // Amount of throttle applied (0.0 to 1.0)
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public float m_steer;                    // Steering (-1.0 (full lock left) to 1.0 (full lock right))
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public float m_brake;                    // Amount of brake applied (0.0 to 1.0)
    [FieldOffset(14)]
    public byte m_clutch;                   // Amount of clutch applied (0 to 100)
    [FieldOffset(15)]
    public sbyte m_gear;                     // Gear selected (1-8, N=0, R=-1)
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public ushort m_engineRPM;                // Engine RPM
    [FieldOffset(18)]
    public byte m_drs;                      // 0 = off, 1 = on
    [FieldOffset(19)]
    public byte m_revLightsPercent;         // Rev lights indicator (percentage)
    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public UInt16Quad m_brakesTemperature;     // Brakes temperature (celsius)
    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public UInt16Quad m_tyresSurfaceTemperature; // Tyres surface temperature (celsius)
    [FieldOffset(36)]
    public UInt16Quad m_tyresInnerTemperature; // Tyres inner temperature (celsius)
    [FieldOffset(44)]
    public ushort m_engineTemperature;        // Engine temperature (celsius)
    [FieldOffset(46)]
    public SingleQuad tyresPressure;         // Tyres pressure (PSI)
    [FieldOffset(62)]
    public ByteQuad m_surfaceType;           // Driving surface, see appendice
};
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, Size = 8)]
public struct UInt16Quad
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort A;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort B;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public ushort C;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public ushort D;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, Size = 16)]
public struct SingleQuad
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float A;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public float B;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public float C;
    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public float D;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, Size = 4)]
public struct ByteQuad
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte A;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte B;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte C;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte D;
}
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.SizeOf<PacketHeader>());
        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.SizeOf<CarTelemetryData>());
        Console.WriteLine(bytes.Length);
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> remaining = bytes;
        var header = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, PacketHeader>(remaining)[0];
        remaining = remaining.Slice(Unsafe.SizeOf<PacketHeader>());
        Console.WriteLine($"{header.m_packetFormat} {header.m_gameMajorVersion}, {header.m_gameMinorVersion}: {header.m_packetId}");
        switch (header.m_packetId)
        {
            case PacketType.CarTelemetry:
                // we expect 20*CarTelemetryData, then a uint of the buttons
                // note we *could* use a fixed buffer for this, but... that's really very
                // awkward to work with; let's try this instead
                int carIndex = 0;
                foreach (var telemetry in MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, CarTelemetryData>(remaining).Slice(0, 20))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"car: {carIndex}, speed: {telemetry.m_speed}, throttle: {telemetry.m_throttle}");
                    var temps = telemetry.m_tyresInnerTemperature;
                    Console.WriteLine($"  type temps: {temps.A}/{temps.B}/{temps.C}/{temps.D}");
                }
                remaining = remaining.Slice(20 * Unsafe.SizeOf<CarTelemetryData>());
                var buttons = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, uint>(remaining)[0];
                Console.WriteLine($"Buttons: {buttons}");
                remaining = remaining.Slice(sizeof(uint));
                Console.WriteLine($"Unaccounted for: {remaining.Length}");
                break;
        }

    }

    static readonly byte[] bytes = new byte[] {
        0xE3, 0x07, 0x01, 0x15, 0x01, 0x06, 0xF8, 0xCE, 0xBE, 0x09, 0x64, 0x7F, 0xEA, 0xD1, 0xDC, 0xA1, 0x16, 0x41, 0x91, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x7B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x36, 0x53, 0x7E, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xF3, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x64, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x1B, 0xF2, 0x3A, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x35, 0x2D, 0x00, 0x22, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xF3, 0x59, 0xA1, 0xBA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x59, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x64, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xFE, 0x5F, 0x3F, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x3D, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x71, 0x00, 0x71, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x81, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x89, 0x78, 0x23, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xE0, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00, 0x78, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xC3, 0x73, 0x98, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x2F, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x54, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xF3, 0xF4, 0xBA, 0xBA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x21, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x59, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x4D, 0x7D, 0x04, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xFB, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x64, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x84, 0x45, 0xAB, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xBF, 0x2D, 0x00, 0x31, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xB5, 0x8C, 0xBD, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x1B, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x71, 0x00, 0x71, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xF8, 0xD0, 0x87, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x63, 0x2C, 0x00, 0x37, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x79, 0x00, 0x79, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xA7, 0x60, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xDE, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x64, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xB9, 0x2E, 0x2F, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xD1, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x64, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xCD, 0x1E, 0x18, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x3F, 0x2D, 0x00, 0x23, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x15, 0x0F, 0xAF, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xA5, 0x2B, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x2B, 0xC0, 0x14, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x49, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x64, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x41, 0xCA, 0xC0, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x85, 0x2B, 0x00, 0x64, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x79, 0x00, 0x79, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x07, 0x1F, 0xD5, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xDE, 0x2A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x78, 0x00, 0x78, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x71, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0xDD, 0xC0, 0x1C, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xDD, 0x2A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x97, 0x96, 0x96, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x9B, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x62, 0x00, 0x62, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x59, 0x00, 0x59, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0xCD, 0xCC, 0xA8, 0x41, 0xCD, 0xCC, 0xA8, 0x41, 0x33, 0x33, 0xBB, 0x41, 0x33, 0x33, 0xBB, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is a *layout* problem to to with padding, you can use explicit field layout to put the fields where you expect them. However, if there is also an *endianness* concern, it will be more complex. If we ignore endianness, perhaps:

```cs
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, Size = 23)]
    public struct PacketHeader
    {
        public static PacketHeader Read(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes)
            => MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, PacketHeader>(bytes)[0];
        public void Write(Span<byte> bytes)
            => MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, PacketHeader>(bytes)[0] = this;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ushort m_packetFormat;         // 2019
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public byte m_gameMajorVersion;     // Game major version - "X.00"
        [FieldOffset(3)]
        public byte m_gameMinorVersion;     // Game minor version - "1.XX"
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public byte m_packetVersion;        // Version of this packet type, all start from 1
        [FieldOffset(5)]
        public byte m_packetId;             // Identifier for the packet type, see below
        [FieldOffset(6)]
        public ulong m_sessionUID;           // Unique identifier for the session
        [FieldOffset(14)]
        public float m_sessionTime;          // Session timestamp
        [FieldOffset(18)]
        public uint m_frameIdentifier;      // Identifier for the frame the data was retrieved on
        [FieldOffset(22)]
        public byte m_playerCarIndex;       // Index of player's car in the array
    };
```

Note also the use of `MemoryMarshal` here which makes coercion a lot easier. `byte[]` can be treated as a span.