# Sending UDP packets In the format of Codemasters F1 2021

Tags: c#, visual-studio, udp, packet

I'm trying to send UDP packets that are usually sent from the game F1 2021. The purpose is to have simhub detect UDP packets without F1 2021 actually running.

The format of sending the UDP is here https://github.com/raweceek-temeletry/f1-2021-udp

I do not know how to write a visual studio program using C# to send this data. I want a program that fakes:

- Motion Packets (for one car)
- Car Telemetry Packet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231960/f1-2019-udp-decoding) can help you?

Comment: I need to send UDP in that format. The post seemed to focus on receiving UDP. Am I understanding what you linked to me?